# ProcessBuilder is not working correctly when I deploy my Spring boot Application to a Linux server

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, processbuilder, opa

```
 public void pushDataToOPA() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-X", "PUT", "-H", "\"Content-Type: application/json\"", "-d",
            "@data.json", dataUrl);
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();

}
```

When I deploy my spring boot application to a Linux server, this data.json file is not put to the target (dataUrl) when this pushDataToOPA method is called. But when I run my application in locally, it successfully puts the JSON file to the same target (dataUrl).

```
 public void updatePolicy() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-X", "PUT", "--data-binary", "@policy.rego", policyUrl);
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();
}
```

but this method is working on both sides.

Comment: Is the file `data.json` present in the linux server?

Comment: yes, data.json present in the Linux server

Comment: Did you tried redirecting the logs from process?

Comment: no, how do I do it? can you explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the process output to a `file` with the following code:

```
public void updatePolicy() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.command("curl", "-X", "PUT", "--data-binary", "@policy.rego", policyUrl);
        pb.redirectOutput(new File("outputfilePath"));
        pb.redirectError(new File("errorFilePath"));
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        }

public void pushDataToOPA() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "-X", "PUT", "-H", "\"Content-Type: application/json\"", "-d",
                "@data.json", dataUrl);
        pb.redirectOutput(new File("outputfilePath"));
        pb.redirectError(new File("errorFilePath"));
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
    }
```

For more details on how to redirect logs read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-processbuilder-class-java/)

Comment: updatePolicy() method is working correctly, should I add these to pushDataToOPA method ?

Comment: added `pushDataToOPA` to the answer

Comment: need to create outputfile and errorfile ? txt files?

Comment: It will automatically create just provide a proper path

Comment: "400 Bad Request: invalid header name" this error returned in the errorFile

Comment: Read about 400 error from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: Removed the "-H". Then it is working. Thanks a lot.